# Counting dummy variables for each person in SAS?

Tags: count, sas

I have a large data set that has multiple rows for each individual. Each individual has a unique ID, and each row is coded as a  dummy 1 or a 0 as to the type of doctor's visit it is. IE: A visit can be at the doctor's office, so if it is, it is coded as 1, if it is not, it is coded by 0. I want to count how many of each visits to each type of doctor each individual has. I tried using the count distinct:

```
proc sql;
create table all as select ID;
count (distinct doctor) as doctor1
from data
group by ID;
quit;
```

However, this does not seem to be giving me what I want.
Any help or pointers on what codes to use would be really appreciated.

Sample data:

```
data this;
datalines;
rid dateofvisit doctor hospital clinic;
 1   1/1/2014    1      0      0
 1   1/3/2014    0      1      0
 2   1/5/2014    1     0        0
 3   1/6/2014    1      0      0
 1   1/7/2014    1     0       0
 3   1/8/2014    0       0    1
```

Comment: I can make some assumptions, but I think it's best if you post sample data. Also, you SAS code above isn't valid as you have too many semicolons. I'll assume that's a type for SO.

Answer (score 1):

The count function will normally count all occurrences. Together with distinct, it will count the number of different kinds of occurances. This is not your wish, if I understand you correctly.

Since your occurances is coded with ones, you could use the sum function to calculate how many times your patient has visited the different kinds of doctors.

```
proc sql;
create table all as select rid,
  sum (doctor) as doctor_visits,
  sum (hospital) as hospital_visits,
  sum (clinic) as clinic_visits,
  sum(sum(doctor, hospital, clinic)) as total_visits
from this
group by rid;
quit;
```